# How do I include linked entries when updating Algolia from Contentful?

Tags: algolia, contentful

I'm currently using a Contentful webhook to automatically update Algolia when a Contentful entry is published.

My content model on Contentful looks something like this:

```
MOVIE:

{ title: string,
  director: reference }
```

```
DIRECTOR:

{ name: string }
```

I am sending content to Algolia via the Contentful webhook. Currently, the data I'm sending looks like this:

```
  title: "Vertigo",
  director: {
    sys: {
      type: "Link",
      linkType: "Entry",
      id: 123456789
    } 
  }
```

Instead, I would like it to be:

```
  title: "Vertigo",
  director: {
    name: "Alfred Hitchcock"
  }
```

How can I include the full data from the linked entry, rather than just the ID? For the record, I'm using a custom webhook payload, which looks basically like this:

```
{
  "title": "{ /payload/fields/title/en-US }",
  "director": "{ /payload/fields/director }"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, to follow links, you're going to have to move beyond the out-of-the-box webhook and write your own connection.

> Inclusion of referenced item data in webhooks Depending on your use
> case you might want to index an entry and all the data that it links
> because it it is a composition of different Contentful entities.
> Reference entry data is not available in the webhook payload and it’s
> recommended to write your own logic to feed Algolia then. The
> Contentful client libraries provide a way to retrieve [linked data](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/links/).

Source: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/enhancing-search-experience-with-algolia/